# Inferring width of gatsby-image based height and aspect ratio

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I define an `Img` with `gatsby-image`, and unless I give a specific width and height for the image the image won't appear. This is an example of something that works, but isn't sized perfectly.

```
<Link style={{height: 200px; width: 100%;}} to="/">
  <Img 
      className='w-100 h-100'
      fluid={logoImgProps}
      imgStyle={{objectFit: 'contain' }}
  ></Img>
</Link>
```

I would like to specify only one dimension, and have the other dimension inferred from the aspect ratio of the image, so that I could do something like this.

```
<Link style={{width: 100%;}} to="/">
  <Img 
      className='w-100'
      fluid={logoImgProps}
  ></Img>
</Link>
```

With this component, my width get's set correctly, but the height is 0. 
Is there a way to specify the size of only one dimension with `gatsby-image` and have the other dimension inferred by the aspect ratio?

---

**Sidenote:** I have no problem with inferring the height based on the width and aspect ratio.

Comment: When I test your second example, it seems to work the way you want it (assuming'w-100' sets `width` to 100%). See this component in this example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-darkness-iun3y?file=/src/components/bio.js:816-1013

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch My graphql query was wrong. Once I started using `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` it worked, previously I had just been using `                fluid(maxWidth: 400) {
                  src
                  srcSet
                  sizes
                  srcSetWebp
                }`, which I think I copied from a starter.

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch It looks like it infers the height when you specify the width, but not the other way around